# MathOverflow is on SE2.0

Tags: discussion

[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is now on SE2.0.

Would we like to open the migration path from/to MO?

Comment: YES YES YES of course

Comment: Do we often have questions that we would like to migrate to MO? And since our scope is a subset of MO's scope, will they ever want to migrate here?

Comment: @Robin, I am not sure that we are completely a subset of MO, many questions here would be unsuitable for MO. There are sometimes questions that might be more suitable on MO but we haven't had many of them. So it seems we don't really need the path that much. And looking at [the discussion over MO](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/141) it seems that there are other sites like [TeX.SE] that have higher priority to cstheory for MO users regarding migration paths. So it seems to me we won't get migration paths between MO and cstheory.

Comment: The main site that would be really helpful to have a migration path to is [cs.se] but until they graduate it is unlikely that migration path is opened.

Comment: @RobinKothari: Until recently, I don't think we had many questions that we'd want to migrate to MO, but recently there have been quite a number of such questions.

Answer (score 6):

We have recently had a spate of questions asked that should be migrated to MO, so I think it would be useful to open a migration path from cstheory.SE to MO.

Comment: We can already migrate to MO by choosing it as the target site in the close dropdown.

Comment: @SureshVenkat: Really? I think maybe *you* can because of your moderator status, but us lowly mortals still don't have the option to even systematically suggest it (unless I missed it). I tried just now and all I could suggest migrating to were: cs.SE, meta.cstheory.SE, or stackoverflow. Or maybe I confused the question (migrating vs. the ability to suggest migrating a question)?

Comment: Ah. the AMP strikes again.

Comment: @SureshVenkat: "AMP"?

Comment: Awesome Moderator Powers